# Meaning of negative elements in Principal Component Analysis(PCA) rotated component matrix

Tags: spss, pca, rotation

Suppose that we have this rotated component matrix from PCA (SPSS output):

```
        Rotated Component Matrix    
               Component    
               1       2
VAR00001     .944   -.008
VAR00002    -.018    .978
VAR00003     .918   -.064
VAR00004     .835   -.169
VAR00005     .608    .189
*Extraction Method: Principal Component Analysis. 
*Rotation Method: Varimax with Kaiser Normalization.        
*Rotation converged in 3 iterations.
```

What is meaning of negative values in this matrix? for example `-.018` in component 1 and `-.008` in component 2? The effect of `VAR00001` is negative on component 1?

Comment: Be the matrix of loadings rotated or not - the loadings are (when you based the analysis on correlations between variables) the correlations between the variables and the components. Correlations, you know, can be positive or negative.

Comment: P.S. In an oblique rotation you would have got two matrices: pattern and structure. Correlations are in the "structure" one.